# Converting Timestamp from one timezone to another

Tags: sql, oracle11g, toad

```
    A Table named TRADES has the following structure and Data:

    CREATE TABLE trades (
        trade_id                NUMBER,
        trade_execution_tmstmp  TIMESTAMP(6),
        time_zone_name          VARCHAR2 (30 BYTE),
        last_trade_marker       TIMESTAMP(6)
);
```

[image]

```
trade_id -- Unique ID for every trade
```

trade_execution_tmstmp -- Time when the trade got executed in EST
time_zone_name -- local time zone for the trade
last_trade_marker -- time in EST for the last trade for a particular day

Requirement goes like this:
I have to develop a procedure which inserts next day trades in another table next_day_trades.

If the procedure is run on 2nd Jan (in this case), there would be only 1 next day trade with trade_id = 4. So, next_day_trades table would have 1 record.

The logic for deciding next day trade is as follows:
trade_execution_tmstmp is in EST. It has to be converted to local timestamp to see when the trade was actually executed in the local market. In this case, Australia/Sydney
for all trades.
last_trade_marker is the time for the last trade in that market.

Below is an explanation the 3rd and 4th record in the table.

Trade 3 is executed at '1/2/2015 1:00:00.000000 PM' (EST).
Its equivalent to Australia/Sydney time would be '1/3/2015 4:00:00.000000 AM'
Last Trade Marker for 2nd Jan is '1/3/2015 2:00:00.000000 AM'
If the trade is executed between 12:00 - 02:00 AM (Last Trade Marker), it would be a next day trade.
So, trade 3 is not a next day trade.

Trade 4 is executed at '1/2/2015 10:00:00.000000 AM' (EST).
Its equivalent to Australia/Sydney time would be '1/3/2015 1:00:00.000000 AM'
Last Trade Marker for 2nd Jan is '1/3/2015 2:00:00.000000 AM'
If the trade is executed between 12:00 - 02:00 AM (Last Trade Marker), it would be a next day trade.
So, trade 4 is a next day trade.

Note: Next Day trades have to be included only for the Stored Proc execution day. That is why, only trade 4 is inserted in next_day_trades table and not trade 2, if the Proc is run on 2nd Jan.

Please help me in coming up with a SELECT query for inserts.

Comment: what is that 'Last Trade Marker' means for? why are you taking particularly 12-2.00 AM period?

Comment: Last Trade Marker is the final time for a trade to be included for today's trade. I am taking 12 - LTM time as this is the business need. I think I can also replace this condition with trade_execution_tmstmp < LTM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert your EST times to the declared time zone in two steps; first by declaring which time zone the original values are in with `from_tz()`, and then using the `at time zone` conversion operator.

You need to convert the last trade marker to a timestamp with time zone too, and because you also need to trap the start of that day (for your 00:00-02:00 range) you need to truncate that - which makes it a date - before applying the `from_tz()` to that.

```
select trade_id, trade_execution_tmstmp, time_zone_name, last_trade_marker,
  from_tz(trade_execution_tmstmp, 'EST') at time zone time_zone_name
    as trade_execution_local_tmstmp,
  from_tz(cast(trunc(last_trade_marker) as timestamp), time_zone_name)
    as last_trade_marker_start,
  from_tz(last_trade_marker, time_zone_name) as last_trade_marker_end
from trades;
```

With session altered to format the values slightly differently:

```
alter session set NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS';
alter session set NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS TZR';
```

That gets:

```
  TRADE_ID TRADE_EXECUTION_TMSTM TIME_ZONE_NAME   LAST_TRADE_MARKER     TRADE_EXECUTION_LOCAL_TMSTMP         LAST_TRADE_MARKER_START              LAST_TRADE_MARKER_END              
---------- --------------------- ---------------- --------------------- ------------------------------------ ------------------------------------ ------------------------------------
         1 2015-01-01 13:00:00   Australia/Sydney 2015-01-02 02:00:00   2015-01-02 05:00:00 AUSTRALIA/SYDNEY 2015-01-02 00:00:00 AUSTRALIA/SYDNEY 2015-01-02 02:00:00 AUSTRALIA/SYDNEY
         2 2015-01-01 10:00:00   Australia/Sydney 2015-01-02 02:00:00   2015-01-02 02:00:00 AUSTRALIA/SYDNEY 2015-01-02 00:00:00 AUSTRALIA/SYDNEY 2015-01-02 02:00:00 AUSTRALIA/SYDNEY
         3 2015-01-02 13:00:00   Australia/Sydney 2015-01-03 02:00:00   2015-01-03 05:00:00 AUSTRALIA/SYDNEY 2015-01-03 00:00:00 AUSTRALIA/SYDNEY 2015-01-03 02:00:00 AUSTRALIA/SYDNEY
         4 2015-01-02 10:00:00   Australia/Sydney 2015-01-03 02:00:00   2015-01-03 02:00:00 AUSTRALIA/SYDNEY 2015-01-03 00:00:00 AUSTRALIA/SYDNEY 2015-01-03 02:00:00 AUSTRALIA/SYDNEY
```

You can compare those adjusted column values to decide if it should be a next day trade, according to the rules as I understand them:

```
select trade_id, trade_execution_tmstmp, time_zone_name, last_trade_marker,
  case when from_tz(trade_execution_tmstmp, 'EST') at time zone time_zone_name
     between from_tz(cast(trunc(last_trade_marker) as timestamp), time_zone_name)
       and from_tz(last_trade_marker, time_zone_name)
     then 'Yes' else 'No' end as next_day_trade
from trades;

  TRADE_ID TRADE_EXECUTION_TMSTM TIME_ZONE_NAME   LAST_TRADE_MARKER     NEXT_DAY_TRADE
---------- --------------------- ---------------- --------------------- --------------
         1 2015-01-01 13:00:00   Australia/Sydney 2015-01-02 02:00:00   No            
         2 2015-01-01 10:00:00   Australia/Sydney 2015-01-02 02:00:00   Yes           
         3 2015-01-02 13:00:00   Australia/Sydney 2015-01-03 02:00:00   No            
         4 2015-01-02 10:00:00   Australia/Sydney 2015-01-03 02:00:00   Yes
```

'Between' might not be the right choice here; depends if a trade at exactly 02:00:00.0 is counted as next day. You might need the equivalent of

```
trade_execution_local_tmstmp >= last_trade_marker_start
and trade_execution_local_tmstmp < last_trade_marker_end
```

Either way you can use that same condition to decide which rows to copy to your separate table.